# How to create fact table using python in ETL project

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, schema, etl

I have to create a fact table in a new project using python. Can anyone help me to create the below structure. The first table is my input transactional table -

| Order ID | Order Date | Region | Sales | Profit | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CA-2013-152156 | 09-11-2014 00:00:00 | East | 261.96 | 41.9136 | 9 |
| CA-2013-138688 | 2014-06-13 00:00:00 | West | 14.62 | 6.8714 | 2 |
| US-2012-108966 | 2013-10-11 00:00:00 | South | 957.5775 | -383.031 | 5 |
| CA-2011-115812 | 2012-06-09 00:00:00 | West | 48.86 | 14.1694 | 7 |

The output will be similar to the below table . Basically I need to create a fact table with two new columns -1) Measure and 2)Values . Sales, Profit and Quantity columns needs to be transposed in the second table along with other attribute columns.

| Order ID | Order Date | Region | Measure | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CA-2013-152156 | 2014-11-09 00:00:00 | South | Sales | 261.96 |
| CA-2013-152156 | 2014-11-09 00:00:00 | South | Profit | 41.9136 |
| CA-2013-152156 | 2014-11-09 00:00:00 | South | Quantity | 2 |
| CA-2013-138688 | 2014-06-13 00:00:00 | West | Sales | 14.62 |
| CA-2013-138688 | 2014-06-13 00:00:00 | West | Profit | 6.8714 |
| CA-2013-138688 | 2014-06-13 00:00:00 | West | Quantity | 2 |
| US-2012-108966 | 2013-10-11 00:00:00 | South | Sales | 957.5775 |
| US-2012-108966 | 2013-10-11 00:00:00 | South | Profit | -383.031 |
| US-2012-108966 | 2013-10-11 00:00:00 | South | Quantity | 5 |

I have used a small dataframe from sample superstore data for example purposes

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put the dataframes in text form? So we can copy-paste it?

Comment: I don't understand required output. You have to explain it.

Comment: expected output looks like created with `groupby([id, date, region])` and `sum()` on `sales,profit` and later use `pivot`

Comment: I have edited the tables. can any one guide me. Group by option is not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

- your sample data does not match your desired output ....
- it's a simple case of `groupby()` all columns except **Value**
- then `unstack("measure")`

```
import io
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'Order ID': ['CA-2013-152156',
  'CA-2013-152156',
  'CA-2013-152156',
  'CA-2013-138688',
  'CA-2013-138688',
  'CA-2013-138688',
  'US-2012-108966',
  'US-2012-108966',
  'US-2012-108966'],
 'Order Date': ['2014-11-09 00:00:00',
  '2014-11-09 00:00:00',
  '2014-11-09 00:00:00',
  '2014-06-13 00:00:00',
  '2014-06-13 00:00:00',
  '2014-06-13 00:00:00',
  '2013-10-11 00:00:00',
  '2013-10-11 00:00:00',
  '2013-10-11 00:00:00'],
 'Region': ['South',
  'South',
  'South',
  'West',
  'West',
  'West',
  'South',
  'South',
  'South'],
 'Measure': ['Sales',
  'Profit',
  'Quantity',
  'Sales',
  'Profit',
  'Quantity',
  'Sales',
  'Profit',
  'Quantity'],
 'Value': [261.96, 41.9136, 2.0, 14.62, 6.8714, 2.0, 957.5775, -383.031, 5.0]})

df.groupby([c for c in df.columns if c!="Value"]).sum().unstack("Measure").droplevel(0,1).reset_index()
```

|  | Order ID | Order Date | Region | Profit | Quantity | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | CA-2013-138688 | 2014-06-13 00:00:00 | West | 6.8714 | 2 | 14.62 |
| 1 | CA-2013-152156 | 2014-11-09 00:00:00 | South | 41.9136 | 2 | 261.96 |
| 2 | US-2012-108966 | 2013-10-11 00:00:00 | South | -383.031 | 5 | 957.577 |